# Bootstrap adding more margin on right

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, jinja2

I ran into an issue working with bootstrap.

I am trying to have 4 "cards", or product cards (that I would like to be able to modify myself), but I am having an issue doing it. I want them to be 4 on each row, with a height of 380px and width of 250px, when I am adding my 50px margin in between each card, there is a lot of margin on the right side, but barely anything on the left side which makes my cards not be in the middle.

When I use the developer tool it looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y9g9o.jpg)

How do I fix this?

Here is my HTML (using Jinja):

```
<h1 class="title">Bazaar Prices</h1>
<h4 class="sub-title">*Updating every 5 seconds*</h4>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    {% for product in products %}
    <div class="card col-xl-3">
      <img class="card_img" src="../static/img/instagram.png" />
      <h4 class="card_title">
        {{ product.id|replace("_", ' ')|lower()|title() }}
      </h4>
      {% for buy in product.buy_price%}
      <p>Buy Price: {{ buy.pricePerUnit }}</p>
      {% endfor %} {% for sell in product.sell_price%}
      <p>Sell Price: {{ sell.pricePerUnit }}</p>
      {% endfor %}
      <p>Buy Volume: {{ product.buy_volume }}</p>
      <p>Sell Volume: {{ product.sell_volume }}</p>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Not tested but may this work `<div class="card col-12 col-xl-3">`

Comment: I changed up my design for my version 1.0 release, will keep this in mind tho, thanks!